# CNC-Vcarve: 45° Bevel on 3/4" Board with 1/2 v-Bit

Tags: router, cnc

I'd like to put a 45° bevel (miter) on one edge of a 3/4" board with a 1/2 " 90° V-bit I already own.  This seems like it should be possible, but I am having issues 1) figuring out myself; or 2) finding straight-forward discussion or solution online.

Currently, my toolpath is set as a profile, with 'machine vectors' set to 'on'.  All I get is a pocket of given length with 1/2" 'V' profile at bottom and straight sides rest of the way to surface of material.  No bueno...any thoughts?

Comment: Caveat: I know zip about CNC on a hands-on level. But this seems like it should be possible. What's needed is to extend the 45° surface at the bottom of the channel upwards yes? Can you create a new toolpath offset to each side of the existing one where it'll carve away one or both of the 'shoulders' of the channel?

Comment: @Graphus: what you are suggesting is certainly possible.  But the designer (me) would then have to make calculations up that slope as to height and depth and be perfectly correct (CNC stuff is deal in tolerances of ~.001).  So really hard to do manually...but I agree with your general point: this seems doable, and in addition, often needed, hence my question.

Comment: If that is a way to do it then surely the maths for the new path(s) is fairly trivial (if you're already mathematically proficient enough to do CNC programming I mean!)? Being a 45° angle it makes the calculations relatively easy I would have thought, since the amount up and across will be equal.